# user login not working in node.js and mlab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, mlab

i have users database(username,password) in mlab and want to login by checking that user existing in database but it always throws alert that wrong username/passwd even it is existing in database.

server.js:

```
     app.post('/check-login',(req,res)=>{
x=users.findOne({username:req.body.username,password:req.body.password}, 
            function(err, data) {
    console.log(data)
    if(data.length==1)
    {
        res.send({"message":"success"})

    }
    else{
        res.send({"message":"Wrong Username Or Password"})
    }
})


    })
```

login.js:

```
    handlePress() {
console.log("Hello");
axios.post("http://192.168.43.239:8081/check-login", {
  username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res["data"])
  if(res["data"]["message"] == "success") {
    alert("Login Successfully");
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  }
  else {
    alert("Wrong Username Or Password")
  }
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
      };
```

Comment: check mlab connection string 
 the actual error should not be wrong username or password because you hardcoded it.

Comment: properly console your and do the action based on that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**server.js**

FindOne query returns an object and you are checking it's length which will always be false.

try this:

```
app.post('/check-login',(req,res)=>{
x=users.findOne({username:req.body.username,password:req.body.password}, 
            function(err, data) {
    console.log(data)
    if(data)
    {
        res.send({"message":"success"})

    }
    else{
        res.send({"message":"Wrong Username Or Password"})
    }
})


    })
```